# What software should I use to mine alt coins?

Tags: mining-profitability

I downloaded MUE wallet.

I have GTX 1060 in one of my computer and I want to mine. It's the same GTX I used to play overwatch.

However, I am confused.

How do I mine MUE?

Is there a software for that?

How do I mine quark or x11 based tools?

I check https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=778322.0

I downloaded the wallet. But how to mine?

If there is a miner that will switch to whatever currency or pool generate most money it would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to download some mining software, cgminer was what I used to use, there are others out there to. But find yourself a pool that has the altcoins u want to mine, most pools work on pointing your port at a different values for the different coins. Most good pools have guides for setting up the different miners software for their pool.  Coinotron was always one of my favourite pools and it is still going :) hope this helps